# How to sync object to controller scope in this little game in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I've made this simple [pairs game](http://joao.pt/w/lab/memo/app/), stuffing all my code in [app.js](http://joao.pt/w/lab/memo/app/scripts/app.js). To play it, you simply have to pair up the cards on the screen: every time you do so, the `card` object is printed to the console, containing game variables such as number of moves, game timer, etc. These game variables should show up on the lower right side of the screen, but I don't seem able to pass them through the `CardFlipper` controller's `$scope`. How should I do this? Should I move my functions and object inside the controller? This is my first time using Angular JS, so please feel free to suggest a better practice or a more efficient way to do this. Here's my app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('memoApp', []);

app.filter('shuffle', function() {
  return function(array) {
    var counter = array.length, temp, index;
    while (counter--) {
        index = (Math.random() * counter) | 0;
        temp = array[counter];
        array[counter] = array[index];
        array[index] = temp;
    } return array;
  }
});

app.directive('card', function() {
  return function(scope, element) {
    element.bind('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      revealCard($(this).children('a'));
      console.log(card);
    });
  }
});

function CardFlipper($scope) {
    $scope.deck = [
      1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
      1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
    ];
    $scope.card = card;
 };

 /* Gaming */

var card = {
  count: 0,
  pair: 0,
  moves: 0,
  timer: 0
};

var timer = setInterval(function(){
  card.timer++;
}, 1000);

var revealCard = function(picked) {
  if (card.count!=1) {
    // First move: store data
    card.pair = picked.data('pair');
    card.count = 1;
    turnCard('wipe');
    turnCard('flip', picked, card.pair);
  } else {
    // Second move: compare
    if (picked.data('pair')==card.pair) {
      if (!picked.hasClass('flip')) {
        turnCard('win', picked, picked.data('pair'));
      } else {
        turnCard('wipe');
      }
    } else {
      turnCard('flip', picked, picked.data('pair'));
    }
    card.count = 2;
    card.moves++;
  }
};

var turnCard = function(outcome, picked, pair) {
  switch (outcome) {
    case 'flip':
      picked.toggleClass('flip').html(pair);
      break;
    case 'win':
      picked.addClass('flip').html(card.pair);
      $('ul#game .flip').addClass('win');
      break;
    case 'wipe':
      $('ul#game li').find('a').removeClass('flip').html('');
      break;
  }
};
```

Comment: Not sure how you could pass the `card` variable around, but as I see it the 'game variables' could very well be attributes of the $rootScope. So you can provide something like a `run()`function in which you would bind the `card` var to $rootScope. The $rootScope is an attribute of any scope, so it can be easily accessed by scope.$rootScope. Doing things this way is nicer because the 'card' variable is not a global variable, but a resource which can be accessed (or even injected ) in your directive, controller, whatever

Comment: Even more on that. IMHO the `turnCard()` and `revealCard()` make more sense to be actions inside your 'CardFlipper' controller since that are exactly the actions that the controller does.

Comment: @victor using $rootScope is definitely not best practice. A simple service , containing object of variable properties needed can be shared across the whole app. Add whatever upDate methods are needed then inject service in controllers and directives that want to share that data

Comment: Yeah actually that would be somewhat of a hack... Since Joao was asking of better way of doing things,  I guess we can be picky and I think the best idea would be to have the 'game statistics' as an isolated scope which listens to $emit(..) events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are relying too much to jQuery to implement your game. You use Angular only to bind jQuery events to DOM elements.

Your game is a great example for someone new to Angular, so I've written my own version of it.

Check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UQwMa/).

Js Code:

```
angular.module('CardFlipperApp', [])
/* Card model */
.factory('Card', function() {
    function Card (number) {
        this.visible = false;
        this.cleared = false;
        this.number = number;
    };
    Card.prototype.show = function() {
        this.visible = true;   
    };
    Card.prototype.hide = function() {
        this.visible = false;   
    };
    Card.prototype.clear = function() {
        this.cleared = true;   
    };
    return Card;
})
/* Deck model */
.factory('Deck', function(Card) {
    function shuffle(array) {
        var counter = array.length, temp, index;
        while (counter--) {
            index = (Math.random() * counter) | 0;
            temp = array[counter];
            array[counter] = array[index];
            array[index] = temp;
        }
        return array;
    }

    function Deck (numberOfCards) {
        var array = [];
        for (var i = 1; i <= numberOfCards; i++) {
            array.push(new Card(i));  
            array.push(new Card(i));
        }
        this.cards = shuffle(array);
    };

    Deck.prototype.hideAllBut = function(card) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.cards.length; i++) {
            if (this.cards[i] !== card) {
                this.cards[i].hide(); 
            }
        }
    };

    Deck.prototype.allCleared = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.cards.length; i++) {
            if (!this.cards[i].cleared) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    };

    return Deck;
})
.controller('CardFlipperCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, Deck) {
    var timeoutHandle = null;

    function nextTick(){
        $scope.timer++;
        timeoutHandle = $timeout(nextTick,1000);
    }

    function startTimer() {
        timeoutHandle = $timeout(nextTick, 1000);
    }

    function stopTimer() {
        if (timeoutHandle) {
            $timeout.cancel(timeoutHandle);
            timeoutHandle = null;
        }
    }

    $scope.init = function() {
        $scope.deck = new Deck(9);
        stopTimer();
        $scope.moves = 0
        $scope.timer = 0;
        $scope.done = false;
    };

    $scope.toggle = function(card) {
        // double click, do nothing
        if ($scope.selectedCard === card) { return; }

        $scope.moves++;
        if ($scope.moves === 1) { // start timer on 1st move
            startTimer();
        }

        if ($scope.selectedCard) {
            if ($scope.selectedCard.number === card.number) {
               $scope.selectedCard.clear();
               card.clear();
               if ($scope.deck.allCleared()) {
                   $scope.done = true;
                   stopTimer();
               }
            } else {
               card.show();
            }
            $scope.selectedCard = null;
        } else {
            card.show();
            $scope.deck.hideAllBut(card);
            $scope.selectedCard = card;   
        }
    };

    $scope.init(); // initial deck creation
});
```

Template:

```
<div ng-app="CardFlipperApp">
    <div ng-controller="CardFlipperCtrl">
        <button ng-click="init()">Reset</button>
        Moves: {{moves}} - Time: {{timer}}
        <div ng-if="!done" ng-repeat="card in deck.cards">
            <div class="card" ng-class="{visible: card.visible, cleared: card.cleared, changeLine: ($index % 6 == 0)}" ng-click="toggle(card)">
                <span ng-if="card.visible">{{card.number}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-if="done" class="done">Done!</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Take note of the use of "models" like Card and Deck. Models are not something specific to Angular (a jQuery app could abstract those entities) but in Angular, models can be registered as services inside the IOC and take advantage of DI (Deck depends on Card, controller depends on Deck).

The way I find best for doing so, is defining a plain JS "class" inside a service (properties, methods, "static" functions etc) and return the contructor to be registered in Angular. Another component that depends on it, simply calls new ModelClass().

Substantial functionality of your app can reside in "models" (code that has nothing to do with Angular). That way, your app is easier to read, understand and test.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to actually code a whole new game. This is my very first shot at Angular JS, and I guess not being more literate in JavaScript doesn't really help much either. I'll spend some more time going through your code and try to learn a little more about models.

Comment: As I said before, you've given a perfect example of a beginner's project. When writting Angular JS apps try to forget everything you know about jQuery. If you're using jQuery APIs, you probably doing it wrong. jQuery is only needed when you use third party widgets which should be encapsulated inside angular directives.